# Error message with iOS music player app

Tags: ios

The below code gives me an error. It gives the error message "Value of type 'UIToolbar' has no member value"

The error occurs on this line: `musicPlayer.volume = volumeSlider.value`

```
musicPlayer.delegate = self
musicSlider.minimumValue = 0
musicSlider.maximumValue = Float(musicPlayer.duration)

musicSlider.value = Float(musicPlayer.currentTime)

// error line below:       
musicPlayer.volume = volumeSlider.value

musicPlayer.play()
songNameLabel.text = musicFiles[currentIndex]
animateSongNameLabel()
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: What is `volumeSlider`? It appears to be a `UIToolbar`.

Comment: So if it is a `UIToolbar`, why are you trying to access the non-existent `value` property from the toolbar?

Comment: Excuse me it may just my lack of understanding. Basically I just want the volume slider changeable at the user's will. Thank You